# Import all file with same head and type

Tags: linux, shell-script

I try to `cat` all files with the same name head and type into one file.

For example, `cat out1.csv out2.csv out3.csv > out.csv`. But my data set is too large to do this; I tried `cat out/*.csv > out.csv`. It did not work.

I am a beginner at shell script. Could someone please tell me what I am wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: You could simply do `cat out?*.csv > out.csv`.

Comment: What does "did not work" actually mean and what do you mean by "head"?  Please include any error messages in your question without modifications. "Head" is commonly interpreted as "header" in relation to CSV files, i.e. the line with the names of the columns.  A "file type" in Unix are things like "regular file", "directory", "symbolic link" etc.  You may possibly have meant "filename prefix" and "filename suffix" (or "filename extension").

Comment: Do you care about the order in which the files are concatenated? I mean if you have `out2.csv` and `out10.csv` do you care if their contents appear in the output such that `out10.csv`s contents appear before `out2.csv`s contents or vice-versa or is any order of `cat`ing the input files OK?

Answer (score 2):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
autoload zargs
zargs -- out<->.csv(n) -- cat > out.csv
```

Would concatenate all the files whose name starts with `out`, is followed by any decimal number and followed by `.csv`, sorted `n`umerically into `out.csv`. Using `zargs` works around the limit on the number of arguments that can be passed to a command by splitting it into several command invocations if necessary.

With the `bash` shell and the GNU implementation of `xargs`, you can do something similar with:

```
xargs -r0a <(
  shopt -s failglob extglob
  pattern='out+([0123456789]).csv' IFS=
  printf '%s\0' $pattern | sort -zV) cat > out.csv
```

Comment: Nice accommodation of the numeric sort order.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
for file in out[0-9]*.csv; do
    cat "$file"
done >out.csv
```

Comment: @StephenKitt It is possibly fixed now. Note that `out.csv` also will be matched by the pattern, but that the file is guaranteed to be empty as it would be the first file in the matched list of names and the redirection would truncate it.  I did not add a description of the solution or why this loop is needed (it should be added by the author, really).

Comment: @Kusalananda I am not sure why you made the change. That code will not work now. There is a difference between > and >>.     >> is to append.

Comment: @Kishan the redirection was moved outside the loop, so this does produce the correct result.

Comment: As I wrote in the edit comment, doing a single redirection of the loop itself rather than X number of appending redirects is more efficient. Since the redirection truncates the output file, it also does not require that you remove the output file before the loop (which you had forgotten to do).

Answer (score 0):

Using the DSU (Decorate/Sort/Undecorate) idiom with any Bourne-derived shell that has `printf` as a built-in and assuming you want the input files printed in increasing numeric order:

```
printf '%s\n' out[0-9]*.csv |
awk -F'[^0-9]+' -v OFS='\t' '{print $2, $0}' |
sort -k1,1n |
cut -f2- |
xargs cat > out.csv
```

The above will work for files with names such as those shown by the OP that do not contain spaces or digits in other locations.

Comment: Note that in many shells `[0-9]` and most common locales, matches on hundreds of different characters, not just 0123456789.

Comment: So how would you categorize the shells that do - Bourne-derived?

Comment: In Bourne-like shells other than `zsh`, if the `out[0-9]*.csv` glob doesn't match any file, but there's a file called literally `out[0-9]*.csv`, its contents will end up in `out.csv`.

Comment: I'm definitely not going to worry about that case as there's no indication that might be a possibility for the OP.

Comment: `out[0-9]*.csv` would match on a file called `$'out1\nfoobar2` or `$'out1 2 3.csv'` or `$'out1"x.csv` causing problems down the line.

Comment: I said `The above will work for files with names such as those shown by the OP that do not contain spaces`. and, again, there's no indication the OP might have esoteric file names so there's no point adding a bunch of unnecessary bells and whistles.

Comment: Yes, those are likely not going to be a problem to the OP, but I think it's still worth point out the limitations. See how my answer tries to avoid all those caveats.

Comment: Regarding `[0-9]` matching non-digits - that's fine, it's really just to separate the input files from `out.csv`. I could have just used `?`.